# Change Root of a Branch to another Branch after Rebase

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, reset, rebase

I use Git for versioning and I'm trying to accomplish something that I'm not sure is possible easily. I have a feature branch `feature1.1` with a few commits in it. I also have a branch seeming off the last commit of that feature `feature1.2`. This is because `feature1.2` depends on `feature1.1` but not necessarily needs to be or want on the same branch.

Currently, when I rebase `feature1.1` I end up having to cherry-pick `feature1.2` into a new branch created after I rebase `feature1.1`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Essentially, I want this

```
                F feature1.2
               /
      C---D---E feature1.1
     /
A---B---G---H---I---J---K master
```

to become this

```
                                      F' feature1.2
                                     /
                          C'---D'---E' feature1.1
                         /
A---B---G---H---I---J---K master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches don't *have* roots.

Well, that's a bit of an overstatement.  The root of `feature1.1` is commit `A`.  So it would be more accurate to say that branches don't have *useful* roots.

What a branch *is*, is a pointer to one specific commit: `feature1.1` points to the commit you have labeled `E`, whose hash depends on its contents and its history all the way back to the root.  Which means you have two *different* commits, both of which you have labeled `E`: one whose parent chain goes `D`, `C`, `B`, ... and one that goes `D`, `C`, `K`, ...

What `git rebase` does is to *copy* commits, to new ones that have different parent hash IDs (and usually different base source trees as well).  The new commits are a lot like the old ones, but are not the same.  So you need to give them new names, like `C'-D'-E'` for instance.

The old commits remain in your repository for a while (at least 30 days by default).  When you copy `C-D-E` to the new chain, that does not affect the original `F`.

Now you need to copy `F` to `F'`.  A problem may occur if you do it naively, with `git checkout feature1.2; git rebase feature1.1`: Git doesn't know that it *shouldn't* copy `C-D-E` any more.  It has `C'-D'-E'` that it can see on the new `feature1.1`, but it doesn't really know these came from `C-D-E`.  If the commits smell enough alike,<sup>1</sup> the rebase notices that it already has them, and skips copying them.  But if they changed enough during the first rebase, it copies them *again*.

To prevent Git from even *looking* at the original `C-D-E` chain, you need `git rebase --onto`.  Or, you can use an interactive rebase: here Git gives you a file with the proposed set of commits to copy, and you can manually delete the ones that are already copied.

Remember that anyone who has their own copies of your original commits (with the same hash IDs as your originals) will retain their copies.  They, too, will have to arrange to start using the *new* copies in place of the old ones.  If you are the only one with these feature branches, or if all your collaborators are prepared to deal with these rebases, you're good to go.  If not, you may be creating more pain than they can handle.

---

<sup>1</sup>In reality, this means "if they have the same [`git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html)".

Comment: thanks! You are correct, I should rename the commits so they are more clear that they aren't truly the same. However, after reading your answer, I do believe an `interactive rebase` is what I'm looking for to use. I've used it before to `squash` commits, and it didn't occur to me that I can use this to ignore certain commits. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `git rebase --onto feature1.1 feature1.1@{1}` to automatically exclude the original commits using the reflog for `feature1.1`. The `@{1}` part depends on exactly one update to the branch-name `feature1.1`, so that the reflog one step back refers to the branch tip commit prior to the copy.

Comment: got it. I'll look into that, though sometimes I also have to make changes to `feature1.1` and that's when `feature1.2` becomes a pain to move around. Maybe those solutions you propose will help a lot in my process. thanks again!

Comment: I never finished working on it, but there's a way to use the `--fork-point` code (see `git merge-base --fork-point`) to have Git automatically figure these things out. I'm not sure that's even the right *path* for a multi-branch-rebase script, but I had *started* on a multi-branch-rebase script and was thinking of using the `--fork-point` code for this kind of thing. Where I got bogged down was in handling multiple branches with complex topologies.

Comment: that sounds interesting. Thanks.